# SQL Oracle Timestamp - arithmetic between two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-arithmetic

I use Oracle database.
In my table, I have one column of type `Timestamp`, and another `Int` column which holds amount of hours.
How I subtract those hours from the other `Timestamp` column?

Meanwhile I have something like that:

```
SELECT (START_TIME - interval 'CLOSING_HOURS' HOUR) as CLOSING_TIME 
 FROM APP.TRUMPS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
SELECT start_time - numtodsinterval( closing_hours, 'hour' ) as closing_time
  FROM app.trumps
```

`numtodsinterval` is the easiest way to convert a number of hours stored in a table (or a PL/SQL variable) into an interval that you can subtract from your timestamp.